# Android Tabs Component with Role for Accessibility?

Tags: android, accessibility

Currently I'm using TabLayout in my Android app, which has `setContentDescription` function to set description, but TalkBack is not able to discern a role (e.g. "Tab"). How can I use an accessibility friendly component that has a role? Can I set it manually somehow?

Answer (score 0):

When using setContentDescription you could provide a role as part of the CharSequence method argument, (e.g. setContentDescription("Settings Tab") ), but it will have no semantical meaning. That said, there will be no way to let the user know how to activate the element for example. To help Screen Readers users this could be an acceptable way. Have in mind that when implementing custom views some extra work must be made to achieve accessibility features, I leave you some reference links. Hope some of this helps.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat#setRoleDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)